# Using enums in Objective C

Tags: objective-c

I have declared an enum in a .h file.

In the Event.h file

```
typedef enum EventType {
    MovementStart = 100019,
    MovementStop = 100020,
    HeartBeat = 100021
} EventType;
```

I have imported Event.h into my ViewController and am trying to use it as:

```
EventType eventType;
NSArray *eventTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:eventType.MovementStart, nil];
```

This is giving me an error: 
Member reference base type 'EventType' (aka 'enum EventType') is not a structure or union.

How do I fix this ?

Comment: Use typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, EventType) { ... }; instead of a raw C enum.  Also because of Objective-C's lack of namespacing, typically the individual enum names should be EventTypeMovementStart, etc to help namespace what enum they came from.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, to reference that enum value, you wouldn't type `eventType.MovementStart`, you should just type `MovementStart`.

Second, your `EventType` enum values are just integers, but you can only store objects in an `NSArray`, so this wouldn't work anyway. You could store it by replacing `eventType.MovementStart` with `[NSNumber numberWithInteger:MovementStart]`, or less verbose, `@(MovementStart)`.

Comment: or rather than the verbose [NSNumber numberWithInteger: MovementStart].  Just @(MovementStart)

Answer (score 1):

Gavin's answer is correct but I'd like to suggest `NSValue` as a more general solution for any time you're trying to store non-object types such as an enum or struct in an array or dictionary: `NSValue`.

`NSValue`'s [purpose in life](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSValue_Class/index.html) is to wrap any non-object type in a container object which can very helpful.

For example:

```
[NSValue value:eventType withObjCType:@encode(EventType)]
```

Again, not a big difference for very simple enums but in general a very useful technique to know.